# Draw circle with google map api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have this simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Google Map API on xhtml</title>
   <style>
    html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
     height: 100%;
    }
   </style>
   <head>
   <body>
    <script>
    //Initialise la map
    function initMap() {                   
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        center: {lat: 48.8534100, lng: 2.3488000},
        zoom: 13,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl:true
      });
    }
    function drawOnclick() {
      alert("clicked");
        var antennasCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: "#FF0000",
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          center: {lat: 48.8534100, lng: 2.34},
          radius:  1000* 100
        });
      }
      </script>
      <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="drawOnclick();" />
      <div id="map">
      </div>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBbns5KFelTGVj8E8FHdlJfdM9lEHHo4OA&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initMap" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to draw a red circle over Paris when I click on the button. The problem is that when I click the button, nothing happens.

What I don't understand is that when I set my `initMap` as follows:

```
//Initialise la map
function initMap() {                   
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    scrollwheel: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: 48.8534100, lng: 2.3488000},
    zoom: 13,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl:true
  });
  var antennasCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: {lat: 48.8534100, lng: 2.34},
    radius:  100
  });
}
```

The circle is drawn. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The map variable is local to the initialize function. To use it in a HTML click function (for the button), it needs to be in the global scope (where the HTML click function runs). To fix it, remove the `var` that declares it outside of the initialize function:

```
// map variable in global scope
var map;
//Initialise la map
function initMap() {
  // initialize the map variable
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  // ...
```

**working code snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  // map variable in global scope
  var map;
  //Initialise la map
  function initMap() {
    // initialize the map variable
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      scrollwheel: true,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      center: {
        lat: 48.8534100,
        lng: 2.3488000
      },
      zoom: 13,
      streetViewControl: false,
      zoomControl: true
    });
  }

  function drawOnclick() {
    // alert("clicked");
    var antennasCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#FF0000",
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: {
        lat: 48.8534100,
        lng: 2.34
      },
      radius: 1000 * 100
    });
    map.fitBounds(antennasCircle.getBounds());
  }
</script>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="drawOnclick();" />
<div id="map">

</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initMap" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```